# Rewrite a package config using use-package

Tags: use-package

I installed a package called `persp-mode` using `package-install`, and the [package docs](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el#when-installing-with-package-install) recommend the following configs in the `user-init-file` (the last two lines are mine, but they work as expected).

```el
(with-eval-after-load "persp-mode-autoloads"
  (setq wg-morph-on nil) 
  (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'(lambda () (persp-mode 1))))

(setq persp-auto-save-opt 0
      persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p"))
```

I'm trying to re-write the above using [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). By following its docs, I've come up with the following

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure t
  :init
  :config (with-eval-after-load 'persp-mode-autoloads
             (setq wg-morph-on nil) 
             (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
             (setq persp-auto-resume-time 0) 
             (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'(lambda () (persp-mode 1)))
           setq persp-auto-save-opt 0
           setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")))
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. `persp-mode` is not available after Emacs starts up, and key binding does not work either.

Any suggestion for the fix?

---1st Update---

Thanks to @Basil answer, I've managed to get the package loaded, but the configurations of the package still do not work. Below is the latest version of the configs

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure t
  :config (with-eval-after-load "persp-mode-autoloads"
           (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0
                 persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")
                 persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak
                 persp-auto-resume-time 0)
           (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)))
```

---2nd Update---

Thanks again to @Basil further comments, below is the latest version of the relevant configs

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure t
  :init (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)
  :config (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p"))
          (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0)
          (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
          (setq persp-auto-resume-time 0))
```

Result: `persp-mode` is loaded as I can see it from `describe-mode`. `describe-variable` shows `persp-keymap-prefix` has value "^Xp" while its original value was "^Cp". However, when pressing `C-x p` returns `C-x p is undefined`, while pressing `C-c p` still works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it doesn't seem to work

The first issue I see is that you replaced the string `"persp-mode-autoloads"` with the symbol `'persp-mode-autoloads` in the first argument to `with-eval-after-load`. These exhibit different semantics, with the former referring to a base filename and the latter to a [named feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html). The file `persp-mode-autoloads.el` does not provide a feature called `persp-mode-autoloads` (and it is very unlikely that some arbitrary Elisp file will), so the body of `(with-eval-after-load 'persp-mode-autoloads ...BODY...)` will never be executed. See [`(elisp) Hooks for Loading`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) for more information on this.

Even if the `persp-mode` package were to be loaded, however, the `:config` clause would still fail because it comprises invalid Lisp syntax. In particular, [`setq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Using-setq.html) is a [special form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Complications.html) which should be parenthesised along with its arguments.

In addition to these two main issues, the package's recommendation to rely on the loading of the file `persp-mode-autoloads` seems unnecessary/fragile/misleading to me, but that's a different matter.

Try the following on for size:

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (setq wg-morph-on nil)
  (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0)
  (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p"))
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode))
```

The reason I have placed all variable and hook settings under `:init` is because they do not in and of themselves rely on the `persp-mode` package being loaded. Should you find it necessary to set a variable after the package is loaded, whether because of its effect on some other initialisation code or personal preference, however, you can just place the relevant settings in the `:config` clause. I do, nevertheless, recommend modifying hook variables independently of the loading of packages (i.e. under `:init`) whenever possible, as this can make one's configuration more modular and declarative in accordance with `use-package`'s philosophy.

**Update**

> I've managed to get the package loaded

Can you please clarify what you mean by this? Do you mean that `persp-mode` is enabled globally immediately after your `user-init-file` is read?

> the configurations of the package still do not work

Again, please elaborate on what behaviour you actually see compared to what you expected, ideally with a clear description of steps you take to reach that stage.

> Below is the latest version of the configs

I notice in your updated `use-package` stanza that you are modifying `after-init-hook` under the `:config` clause. It is unlikely this is what you want, as the `:config` clause is only run after the `persp-mode` package is loaded. At this point, a) `after-init-hook` may have already been run, never to be run again; and b) `(persp-mode)` can be called directly. I suggest you move the `add-hook` call to the `:init` clause instead.

Another effect of the `:config` forms being run after the `persp-mode` package is loaded is that it is redundant to use `with-eval-after-load` to register code to be run after the `persp-mode-autoloads` file is loaded. In other words, if setting the variables you list really does need to take place after the `persp-mode` package is loaded (for reasons you have not described), you should rather write

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)
  :config
  (setq persp-auto-resume-time 0)
  (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0)
  (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")))
```

After taking another look at `persp-mode.el`, however, I notice that `persp-keymap-prefix` has a [custom setter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html), meaning you may need to take extra care when modifying it outside of the [easy customisation interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html). In fact, it is recommended to use that interface in any case where the user is not prepared to analyse and understand the package's code and constantly adapt their custom settings to it. If you are neither opposed to using the easy customisation interface nor determined to use `use-package`, you could

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`load-library`<kbd>RET</kbd>`persp-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-group`<kbd>RET</kbd>`persp-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>

and proceed to customising the variables above and enabling `persp-mode` via the customisation buffer. The resulting `custom-file` will then ensure that the package is loaded and its variables set at the appropriate time.

In response to [OP's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36793/rewrite-a-package-config-using-use-package/36803#comment57932_36803):

> anything that is left under `:init` gets an `Invalid function: ...` error, suggesting settings need to be done after loading the package

I find this hard to believe, as the only function mentioned under the `:init` clause I suggested is `persp-mode`. Perhaps you mean that `persp-mode` is, for some reason, undefined at the time `after-init-hook` is run (please note which function is actually mentioned in the `Invalid function` error message, as you could be witnessing the materialisation of an error unrelated to this particular `use-package` stanza). This then begs the question of how you are installing, activating and loading your packages, which constitutes a new Emacs SE or support question in its own right.

I can, nevertheless, offer some comments/pointers:

The `persp-mode-autoloads` filename suggests you are installing your packages via the built-in `package.el` package manager. By default, packages are activated (their directories are added to `load-path` and their `-autoloads.el` files are evaluated) after reading your `user-init-file` and before running `after-init-hook`. This is not the case if you modify `package-enable-at-startup` or manually call `package-initialize` at an earlier stage. This is described in more detail at [`(emacs) Package Installation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html), which see.

The `persp-mode.el` package correctly autoloads its minor mode `persp-mode`, so that when it is installed and activated correctly, calling `persp-mode` will result in the package being loaded, rather than getting an error. You thus ought to ensure that `package-initialize` is called (or its `load-path` and autoloads effects emulated) in one way or another before calling `persp-mode`.

> `with-eval-after-load` seems to be required

In general, this statement is technically not necessarily false, as anything placed under `:config` is implicitly placed in an `eval-after-load` form. Nevertheless, I disagree with the statement that `(with-eval-after-load "persp-mode-autoloads" ...)` is required, as the `persp-mode-autoloads` file is an internal feature of the `package.el` package manager which should not be relied on by users and whose purpose is to emulate the autoloading mechanism of built-in Emacs libraries. Furthermore, all `-autoloads.el` files are read on package activation (i.e. when `package-initialize` is called), so there's no real deferral taking place. It especially does not make sense to expect `package-mode-autoloads.el` to be read *after* the `persp-mode.el` package is loaded. Please explain why you think such a call to `with-eval-after-load` is required.

**Update++**

> when pressing `C-x p` returns `C-x p is undefined`, while pressing `C-c p` still works

This is probably because, as I mentioned previously, `persp-keymap-prefix` should be customised via its custom setter:

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)
  :config
  (setq persp-auto-resume-time 0)
  (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0)
  (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (customize-set-variable 'persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")))
```

or, equivalently:

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)
  :config
  (setq persp-auto-resume-time 0)
  (setq persp-auto-save-opt 0)
  (setq persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (persp-set-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")))
```

FYI, in [future versions of `use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/pull/508) you may also be able to write something like

```el
(use-package persp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'persp-mode)
  :custom
  (persp-auto-resume-time 0)
  (persp-auto-save-opt 0)
  (persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x p")))
```

From [OP's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36793/rewrite-a-package-config-using-use-package/36803?noredirect=1#comment57964_36803):

> the intended effects of these variable changes do not happen

Is this in reference to `persp-keymap-prefix` or other variables as well? In the latter case, please provide further details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your version as suggested above, but it does not work as anything that is left under `:init` gets an `Invalid function: ...` error, suggesting settings need to be done after loading the package. In addition, `with-eval-after-load` seems to be required. Last, if I put things under `:config`, the package is loaded but the settings do not take effect. I've updated the question to reflect the latest configs

Comment: @MLister Please see my updated answer. I cannot help any further without more details on the errors and expected vs actual behaviours you are witnessing.

Comment: @MLister The main point I'm trying to make is that there is nothing inherently wrong with my original translation to using `use-package`. Any issues resulting from it are specific to customising `persp-mode` and could potentially be interpreted as support issues, thus becoming increasingly off-topic w.r.t. your initial question. I am happy to try and help by explaining relevant topics, but you must provide as much detail as possible for me to do so.

Comment: please see my 2nd update. I think the `setq` statements in `use-package` modify the variable values, but the intended effects of these variable changes do not happen

Comment: @MLister Please see my updated answer and let me know if your problems persist.

Comment: `customize-set-variable` solves the problem. My knowledge with elisp is limited, but the fact that `describe variable` shows one thing while the program does the other still baffles me. In addition, I wonder why `setq` these variables (`persp-keymap-prefix` and others) **outside of** `use-package` work as expected

Comment: @MLister What `describe-variable` is correct, but that does not say anything about how the variable's value is used - some variables need to be set before loading or enabling a mode or by using a custom setter, as you have seen here. If setting `persp-keymap-prefix` outside of `use-package` worked, that means that you should set it under `:init`, rather than under `:config`.

Answer (score 2):

Now `use-package` is a part of GNU Emacs and described on [GNU documentation site](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/use-package.html).

Here is an example of configuration package `nxml-mode`:

- without `use-package`:

  ```
  (require 'nxml-mode)
  (setq nxml-attribute-indent 4
        nxml-auto-insert-xml-declaration-flag nil
        nxml-bind-meta-tab-to-complete-flag t
        nxml-child-indent 4
        nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag t)
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pom\\'" . nxml-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.xml\\'" . nxml-mode))
  ```
- with `use-package`:

  ```
  (use-package nxml-mode
    :ensure nil ;; For non-builtin packages must be set to `t'.
    :custom     ;; Combine `setq' and `set-custom'.
    (nxml-attribute-indent 4) ;; (setq nxml-attribute-indent 4)
    (nxml-auto-insert-xml-declaration-flag nil)
    (nxml-bind-meta-tab-to-complete-flag t)
    (nxml-child-indent 4)
    (nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag t)
    :mode
    ("\\.pom\\'"
     "\\.xml\\'"))
  ```

Comment: How does splitting one's configuration into multiple files relate to the issue at hand?

Comment: Yes, you right. I update my answer.